# Image Sequence to Video using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 7 images and each image has 25 frames. What I need to do is that wander around each image by frames and display it as a video which can be controlled by play, pause and stop buttons.

What I can do is that making a video player that I can easily import a video and play, pause, stop in it. I designed it already but do not have any idea how to make a video from a list of images.

You can view the images at these URLs:

-http://storage.googleapis.com/alyo/assignments/images/0.jpg
- http://storage.googleapis.com/alyo/assignments/images/6.jpg

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Muhammet!  We're a little different from other sites because we have some strict requirements about how to ask questions.  Please show us what you've tried, and clarify your question.   I'd also recommend taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Congratulations on asking your first question.

Comment: Why don't you convert all your images to a single video?

Comment: I just wanted to challange myself! I thought the main idea of JS is retrieving data and process it

Comment: Doesn't coming to SO for (apparently) a complete solution defeat the purpose of challenging oneself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using javscript setTimeout() method and div element like that:

```js
var left = 0;
            var top = 0;
            var minLeft = -512;
            var minBottom = -288;
            var xDecrement = 128;
            var yDecrement = 72;
            var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");
            var imgIndex = 0;
            let imageList = ['http://storage.googleapis.com/alyo/assignments/images/0.jpg','http://storage.googleapis.com/alyo/assignments/images/6.jpg'];
            var playbackStates = {"INIT":0, "RUNNING": 1 , "PAUSE":2};
            var activeState = playbackStates.INIT;
    
            myImage.style.backgroundPositionX = "0px";
            myImage.style.backgroundPositionY = "0px";
            var timerHandler = null;
            var play = function(){
                
                if(timerHandler){
                    clearTimeout(timerHandler);
                    if(activeState === playbackStates.PAUSE){
                        return;
                    }
                }
    
                timerHandler = setTimeout(function(){
                    let pos =parseFloat(myImage.style.backgroundPositionX.replace("px",""));
                    myImage.style.backgroundPositionX = ( pos - xDecrement) + "px";  
                    if(pos <= -512){
                        myImage.style.backgroundPositionX ="0px";
                        pos =parseFloat(myImage.style.backgroundPositionY.replace("px",""));
                        myImage.style.backgroundPositionY = ( pos - yDecrement) + "px";
                        if(pos <= -288){
                            myImage.style.backgroundPositionY = "0px";
                            imgIndex ++;
                            if(imageList.length <= imgIndex) return;
                            myImage.style.backgroundImage = "url("+imageList[imgIndex]+")";
                        }
                    }
                    play();
                }, 160)
            
            };
            
            myImage.style.backgroundImage = "url("+imageList[imgIndex]+")";
            play();
            activeState = playbackStates.RUNNING;
            
            function pause(){
                activeState = playbackStates.PAUSE;
            }
    
            function resume(){
                activeState = playbackStates.RUNNING;
                play();
            }
```

```html
<div style="width:128px;height:72px;" id="myImage"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="pause()" value="Pause"/>
<input type="button" onclick="resume()" value="Resume"/>
```

You can add all your image url's in "imageList" array, also adjust the speed by modify the timeout interval.

Comment: Nice code. But this is not answers the question. How you pause stop and play this...?

Comment: You can dot it by keeping a state variable and run the timer based on the state. I will update my code with stop/play function implementation. Hope this will help

Comment: Really nice algorithm. It taught me so much. Thank you

Comment: While this may be a correct answer, you should probably finish it by adding images so when the snippet is run, the visitor can see it actually working.

Comment: Actually image was there in the question :). I have updated the code snippet with image url's in the question. Thanks @disinfor  for the suggestion.